# need to store n numbers in dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

Here I have a program that prompts the user to enter size of array, then ask user for integers and calculate average. I'm missing something, the numbers are not being stored into the array.

```
int n;
int *sizeOfArr;
double total = 0;
double avg;

cout << "Please enter n, for size of array: ";
cin >> n;

sizeOfArr = new int[n]; //dynamically allocates n amount of memory 

for (int i = 1; n >= i; i++){ 

    cout << "Enter number " << i << ": ";
    cin >> sizeOfArr[n];

    if (sizeOfArr[n] < 0){
        do{
            cout << "Please enter postive number for number " << i << ": ";
            cin >> sizeOfArr[n];
        } while (sizeOfArr[n] <= 0);
    }

    total += sizeOfArr[n];      
}

avg = total / n; //average formula

cout << "\nAverage of the numbers stored in dynamic array = " << avg << endl; //output 

return 0;
system("pause");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use std::vector instead of dynamic array int*. You do not need to ask the user for size(), you can just dynamically add a variable via std::vector.push_back(). The size can be obtained by calling std::vector.size().

Some mistakes in your Code: Your loop starts int i=1; That's wrong. The first index of the array is 0. Same thing when referencing the vector items: you have to set sizeOfArr[i] not sizeOfArr[n].

Now the point to calculate the mean value:
Your calculation runs with int. If you calculate that way your result will be wrong. You should use double to to so.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variable to index `sizeOfArr[]` - you should be using the loop variable `i` as an index. Also, since you're iterating from 1 to n, and not the more usual 0 to n - 1, you need to adjust the index to compensate for this. So, either change all occurrences of:

```
sizeOfArr[n]
```

to:

```
sizeOfArr[i - 1]
```

or change the for loop to the more canonical form:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

and then just use:

```
    sizeOfArr[i]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seems like it's working. Should I change the main part as well.Like sizeOfArr = new int[n - 1]?

Comment: No - you want there to be `n` elements in the array, so keep the allocation as it is. It was only the indexing of the elements in the for loop that was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be `sizeOfArr[i-1]` instead of `sizeOfArr[n]`

Your iteration index `i` starts from 1 but instead array index should start from `0`

Answer (score -1):

Use `sizeOfArr[i]` instead of `sizeOfArr[n]`

Comment: Well, Thanks Sulthan Allaudeen for correcting my post

Comment: Iteration starts from 1 not 0